# Androidスマホで<audio> tagを利用できますか？

Tags: android, html

ネットに接続していない(stand-alone状態の)Androidスマホの同一folderに下記htmlファイル(abc102.html)とmp3 file(abc102.mp3)を入れてあります。

```
  <body>

    <audio controls>
    <source src="abc102.mp3">
    </audio>

  </body>
</html>
```

abc102.htmlをタップするとcontrolsが表示されますが、controlsの再生ボタンをタップしてもabc102.mp3が再生されません。controlsには0.00/0.00とありmp3 fileが認識・読み込みされていないようです。
どうすれば再生ボタンのタップで再生できるようになるでしょうか、ご教示お願いします。

なお、abc102.mp3を直接タップするとスマホ標準のミュージック・再生アプリで正常に再生されますので音声ファイル自体に問題はないと思います。

Answer (score 0):

まず、書き方が間違っています。

```html
<audio src="●" preload="▲" autoplay loop muted controls></audio>
```

●：音楽ファイルのURL
▲：音楽ファイルの先読みのしかた（none、metadata、auto)
none：先読みしない
metadata：音量、トラックリスト、長さのデータだけ先読みする
auto：すべて先読みする

autoplay属性は自動再生
loop属性はループ再生
muted属性は初期状態を消音
contols属性は操作ボタンを表示

読み込むことができる音楽ファイル形式
android･･･デバイスに依存
IOS･･･MP3、AAC、WAVE

Comment: audio要素はsource子要素に対応しているので、質問文のHTMLソースが明確に間違っているということはありません。

Answer (score 0):

質問の書き方でも出来ますが、type属性を付けてください。

```html
    <audio controls>
    <source src="abc102.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>
```

あとはブラウザーがmp3に対応してない可能性があるのかもしれません。
その場合は、他の（wav, ogg)形式の音声データも用意しておいて

```html
    <audio controls>
    <source src="abc102.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    <source src="abc102.wav" type="audio/wav"/>
    <source src="abc102.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
```

としてみてください。